# How to mock a method within a non-mocked class using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I want to test the `Save()` method which is residing inside the `Contributor` class. This method, in turn, opens a dialog which, when finished loading, actions an event that triggers the method that I want to mock - `PushToPortal`.

```
internal class Contributor
{
   private readonly IEntryPointWrapper _entryPoint;
   private readonly ISyncDialog _dialog;
   public event Action OnPushToWeldCompleted;
   
   internal void Save(Document document)
   {
      ...
      void Ptp() => PushToPortal(information);
     _dialog.ShowDialog(Ptp);
   }
}
```

When `ShowDialog` is called, `OnLoadingCompleted += Ptp;` is invoked.

The problem begins just here. `PushToPortal` looks like this:

```
internal virtual void PushToPortal(Information information)
{
   var pushToPortal = Task.Run(() => {
   var result = _entryPoint.ProcessElements(information); 
   });
   pushToPortal.ContinueWith(task => OnPushToPortalCompleted?.Invoke(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Basically, when running the tests, they continue running while the async method is still processing and when asserting, the callback does not retrieve the needed `information` unless I use `Thread.Sleep`, which is not a solution that I'd like.

The **working solution would be**:

```
_entryPointMock.Setup(epm => epm.ProcessElements(It.IsAny<Information>()))
   .Callback<WeldInformation>(information => actualWeldInformation = information)
   .Returns(new InfoResult { Status = Status.Succeed, InfoCount = 1 });

Thread.Sleep(5000);

_contributor.Save(document);
```

I tried mocking the `PushToPortal` method and use a `Callback` to retrieve its arguments, without going into `ProcessElements`, but it does not seem to do anything at all.

```
_entryPointMock.Setup(epm => epm.ProcessElements(It.IsAny<Information>()))
   .Returns(new InfoResult { Status = Status.Succeed, InfoCount = 1 });

var mock = new Mock<Contributor>();
mock.CallBase = true;
mock.Setup(x => x.PushToPortal(It.IsAny<Information>()))
   .Callback<Information>(information => actualInformation = information);

_contributor.Save(document);
```

Therefore, how can I mock `PushToPortal` properly such that I retrieve the `information`, without actually entering the new thread which processes the elements? I am looking for a solution *which does not imply changing the current code **very much*** - an example which I thought of (and would not like to implement) would've been breaking down the functionality and returning a `Task`.

Comment: `OnPushToPortalCompleted?.Invoke()` very much suggests that there exists an `OnPushToPortalCompleted` event that you could subscribe to, which could be used to set a `ManualResetSlimEvent` or twiddle a `TaskCompletionSource` that you wait for in the test. Creating a mock of `Contributor` and then doing nothing with it will indeed do nothing and is not appropriate even if you did use it because it is exactly the class under test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That implies changing the code in order to facilitate the tests and I will keep in mind. However, I am looking to find out whether there's any possibility that I could mock `PushToPortal` in such way that the code inside it is not executed and I only retrieve the argument.

Comment: No, because that means mocking `Contributor`, and `Contributor` is the class you wish to test. Technically it might be possible to create a mock that defers to an actual `Contributor` for the `Save` function, but it would have to copy its internal state over somehow. All of this leads to a solution that's much more complicated and fragile than simply using the class instead of attempting some sort of partial mock. Mocking is done on the level of the class, not the method, and if you find yourself mocking the very class you're supposed to be testing, something's wrong.

Comment: In general, whenever you find yourself in a situation where writing a test is complicated and you would want to change something to make it simpler, it's almost always a sign that the *code under test* could be improved. In this case, that would be the interface of `Contributor` that uses a fire-and-forget method with an event to signal completion, instead of offering a `SaveAsync` (either as a replacement or as an enhancement). That, in turn, is probably to fit in with the UI, which means disentangling the responsibilities... a lot of work that maybe too dear, but not the fault of the test.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, it is much clearer now what is the best way to proceed with this. Will definitely try out your suggestion.